# Get href link by ID webBrowser1 c#

Tags: c#, html, winforms, browser, href

if a have id and i get text i use this

```
var text = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("id").InnerText;
```

how can I get the link href knowing the id

Html

```
<a id="link11" href="/torrent_details/386387353/ubuntu?tab=summary" data-dynamite-selected="true"><b>ubuntu</b>-12.04-desktop-i386.iso</a>
```

Comment: I'm sorry dude, but what is the context? Do you mean, by using javascript? Why are the tags `winforms` and `webbrowser` both on the question?

Comment: a is missing a runat="server" attribute if you're trying to get href in C#.

Comment: if u can use jQuery do                                              var anchorHrefValue = $('#link11').attr('href');

Comment: I think he means using the WinForms WebBrowser control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string href = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("id").GetAttribute("href");
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("link11").GetAttribute("href")
```