# Not working - onserverclick attribute

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I want to add an `onserverclick` event in balise `<a>` as:

```
<a onServerClick="verif" runat="server" href="/annexe/Ajouter/ajout_agence.aspx">Ajouter agence</a>
```

In code-behind I have defined verify as:

```
protected void verif(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["user"].Equals("magasinier"))
    {
        DialogResult result1 = MessageBox.Show("Non autorisé!", "Erreur", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        if (result1 == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            result1 = DialogResult.Ignore;
        }
    }
    else
    { 
        ...
    }
}
```

In the `else`, I want to be redirect automatically to `href` link.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for...

Comment: Use the mouse only, drag the link button on the page, then go to properties and add the onclick, double click on it, and write your code.

Comment: okey, thank you Aristos :)

Answer (score 1):

try this it's working

```
protected void verif(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["user"].Equals("magasinier"))
    {
        DialogResult result1 = MessageBox.Show("Non autorisé!", "Erreur", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        if (result1 == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            result1 = DialogResult.Ignore;
        }
    }
    else
    { 
        Response.Redirect( ((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor)sender).HRef);//sender is your anchor tag. And take it's href attribute and redirect
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
else
    {
       Response.Redirect(yourURL);
    }
```

Comment: no, well actually verif function will be on event onserverclick of many <a> balise and i want to be automatically redirect to href.
something like giving href as a parameter to verif function and use it on code behind like response.redirect(parameter).
thank any way for ur answer

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358151/how-to-get-a-links-title-and-href-value-separately-with-html-agility-pack

Comment: Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658067/get-href-link-by-id-webbrowser1-c-sharp

Comment: okey thank you insomnium :)

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `MessageBox.Show` will not work. The message box would appear on the server (it won't appear at all as asp.net isn't an interactive process), not on the client machine. You could write some JavaScript to handle this:

```
<a id="verif" runat="server" href="/annexe/Ajouter/ajout_agence.aspx">Ajouter agence</a>

<script>
  $("#verif").click(function(e)
  {
     //some ajax call to check if valid
     if (!isValid)
     {
        window.alert("Non autorisé!");
        e.preventDefault();
     }
  });
</script>
```

Notice that you need to write an ajax service to check if the user is valid & return true or false. You should also not depend solely on this, but also check on the server, in case the user tampers with the page, or goes to the URL manually.

Comment: yes thanks a lot simon halsey